# how to transfer data object to html file using phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

I am running this program in phantom js

```
var ejs = require('ejs'),
    page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('./html/weekly.html', function (status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('test4.pdf');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000); 
      }
});
```

This code is working fine and it gives test4.pdf file as output.

weekly.html file is importing data.js file

```
<script src="../data.js"></script>
```

`data.js` file providing a object which is importing in `weekly.html` using jquery.

**data.js**

```
var data = {"hotel": {
  "info": {
    "hotelId": "h4456789",
    "levelId": "6",
    "locationId": "122",
    "aspireLevelId": "8",
    "hotelName": " xdfhjkhgfd",
    "hotelAddress": "delhi, India, 10035",
    "Rank": "#34 of 678 Hotels in New Delhi",
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I am getting data as object, and I want to put that data into html file using phantomJs and after that convert html file into pdf file.

Now I want to import that data (data.js) through `phantomjs`.

If it is not possible than, what is other way ?

Comment: What you mean `dynamic data`? And are you try `evaluate`? [ http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html ]

Comment: @stdob-- dynamic data means data is coming from variable.

Comment: Unclear. Try to clarify your question.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: a) What does this have to do with node.js or jQuery? PhantomJS is a standalone application and it seems you're using plain PhantomJS without a bridge. Perhaps you should remove both tags. b) It's still not clear what you're trying to do. To me, it seems you want to include the `data` JavaScript object on the page in some serialized form, but you haven't given any indication about which form you expect. Does `page.evaluate(function(){ document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data); }); page.render('test5.pdf');` go in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

you can try create a data class in background,in weekly.html you can use @data DataClass,var data=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(data)); I don't know Character does not meet the requirements,this is one of my solution for my understand

Comment: can you refer any link where I can get more detail